# Creating IDs based on Family Status in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these membership data where each member are able to register their family members under them:

| Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | Member |
| Mary Jonas | Member |
| Edith Jonas | Child |
| Arthur Benjamin | Member |
| Jennifer Lauren | Wife |
| Moore Troops | Child |
| Erica Maxine | Child |
| Erin Benjamin | Child |

The family registration for the membership are as such:
John Doe has no family registered under him
Mary Jonas has 1 family member registered under her (Edith Jonas)
Arthur Benjamin has 3 family members registered under him (Jennifer Lauren, Moore Troops, Erica Maxine, and Erin Benjamin.)

> I need to assign IDs for them in which:
> Member    = (number) + "a"
> Wife      = (Member Number) + "b"
> 1st Child = (Member Number) + "c"
> 2nd Child = (Member Number) + "d"
> 3rd Child = (Member Number) + "e"
> and so on....

I would like to be able to input a formula to automatically produce such IDs:

| ID | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | John Doe | Member |
| 2a | Mary Jonas | Member |
| 2b | Edith Jonas | Child |
| 3a | Arthur Benjamin | Member |
| 3b | Jennifer Lauren | Wife |
| 3c | Moore Troops | Child |
| 3d | Erica Maxine | Child |
| 3e | Erin Benjamin | Child |

What I did for now is to number each of the employee first and then created helper column to produce the letters using IF formula, but I only manage to do up to the letter 'c'. I could not produce label for 'd' and 'e' using the IF formula.

Is there anyway I can create these IDs with formula and using as little helper column as possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to work in levels where status 'Member' == status 'Employee'? Any other specifics we need to know? What happens after applying 'z'?

Comment: hey sorry! It was a typo. There is no "employee" status. Just members. What do you mean by applying Z? The system only limits up to 3 children so it will not get to Z if that is what you meant. Thx for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=LET(x,C2:C9,y,x="Member",SCAN(0,y,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))&CHAR(97+SCAN(0,y,LAMBDA(c,d,IF(d,0,c+1)))))
```

Works up to 'z', but you have clarified this should be fine as there is a limit up to 3 children.

Comment: Thank you for this! this formula perfectly solve my problem! its dynamic too! the only problem is that the array formula doesn't allow filters to be applied to them. But I solved it by having a display page where I can manipulate the data and have a copy that is left untouched.

Comment: Hi, how should I edit the formula if the membership "b" is only reserve for the Wife and "c - z" is reserve for the kids?

Comment: If 'Wife' would come before a 'Child' then try: `=LET(x,C2:C9,SCAN(0,x,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="Member",a+1,a)))&CHAR(96+SCAN(0,x,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="Member",1,IF(b="Child",IF(a=1,3,a+1),a+1))))))` @Skaturtle

Answer (score 0):

JvDV made such a nice formula, but I couldn't understand it, so I tried to solve it my way:

you need one helper column for this. It changes the number when there is a new Member in the list.

```
E2  =COUNTIF($C$2:C2;"Member")
```

The other formula is divided in two parts, to understand it a bit easier:

We need to know if the Member of the Familie is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on member.
This is done by this formula:

```
F2  =ROWS(FILTER($E$2:$E$9;($E$2:$E$9=E2)))-ROWS(FILTER(E2:$E$9;(E2:$E$9=E2)))+1
```

Now we convert the number into letters.
1 for a, 2 for b, 3 for c and so on

G2  =CHOOSE(F2;"a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f")

Extend the formula if you need.

Now we put the last two formulas together and add the number from the helper column:

```
I2  =E2&CHOOSE(ROWS(FILTER($E$2:$E$9;($E$2:$E$9=E2)))-ROWS(FILTER(E2:$E$9;(E2:$E$9=E2)))+1;"a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think your formula is much easier to understand and I was able to use filters on them. I would have never thought of using COUNTIFS formula like that! It's Amazing! Thank you :)